# how to handle this in dataframe with python programing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| Acc numb | CityName |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 |  |
| 123456 | Delhi |
| 123456 |  |
| 123456 |  |
| 123456 |  |
| 910234 |  |
| 910234 |  |
| 910234 |  |
| 910324 |  |
| 910324 | Bangalore |
| 910324 |  |
| 910324 |  |
| 360825 |  |
| 360825 |  |
| 360825 |  |
| 360825 | Mumbai |
| 360825 |  |
| 123456 |  |
| 123456 |  |
| 123456 |  |
| 123456 |  |
| 123456 |  |

| Acc numb | CityName |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | Delhi |
| 123456 | Delhi |
| 123456 | Delhi |
| 123456 | Delhi |
| 123456 | Delhi |
| 910234 | Bangalore |
| 910234 | Bangalore |
| 910234 | Bangalore |
| 910324 | Bangalore |
| 910324 | Bangalore |
| 910324 | Bangalore |
| 910324 | Bangalore |
| 360825 | Mumbai |
| 360825 | Mumbai |
| 360825 | Mumbai |
| 360825 | Mumbai |
| 360825 | Mumbai |
| 123456 |  |
| 123456 |  |
| 123456 |  |
| 123456 |  |
| 123456 |  |

Comment: can you explain a little more the logic? why the last `123456` aren't filled? Why `910234` and `910324` are filled with the same value? Do you want to fill based on `Acc numb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to fill `CityName` based on `Acc numb` you can try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = df.replace('',np.nan)

df['CityName'] = df.groupby('Acc numb',group_keys=False).apply(lambda group: group['CityName'].ffill().bfill())
```

**Explanation:**

This code groups by `Acc numb` and fills the missing values in `CityName` using `ffill()` and `bfill()` in order to use the `CityName` found in that group. If there is no `CityName` for certain `Acc numb` the rows will stay as `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

Create consecutive groups by compare shifted values with cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and get first non missing value per groups in new column by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

*Notice: `910234` is different like `910324`, so not filled by `Bangalore`.*

```
g = df['Acc numb'].ne(df['Acc numb'].shift()).cumsum()
df['CityName'] = df.groupby(g)['CityName'].transform('first')
print (df)
    Acc numb   CityName
0     123456      Delhi
1     123456      Delhi
2     123456      Delhi
3     123456      Delhi
4     123456      Delhi
5     910234       None
6     910234       None
7     910234       None
8     910324  Bangalore
9     910324  Bangalore
10    910324  Bangalore
11    910324  Bangalore
12    360825     Mumbai
13    360825     Mumbai
14    360825     Mumbai
15    360825     Mumbai
16    360825     Mumbai
17    123456       None
18    123456       None
19    123456       None
20    123456       None
21    123456       None
```